# Hibernate grouping and result set transformation

Tags: sql, hibernate, grouping, hibernate-mapping

Suppose I have the following result set:

[image]

So, we have one-to-many-to-many relation here. 
The question is what would be the best way to group it in Hibernate and convert this data structure to DTO with fields like:

`String countryName
String companyName
List invoiceNumbers`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For `Country` and `Company`  ---- `Many-to-Many`
For Company and Invoice --- `One-to-Many`

```
@Entity
public class Country {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="countries")
private Collection<Country> countries;
...
getters and setters

}

@Entity
public class Company {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany
private Collection<Country> countries;

@OneToMany
private Collection<Invoice> invoices; 
...
getters and setters

}

@Entity
public class Invoice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private int invoice_number;
...
getters and setters

}
```